# Need to list how many comments a delivery has in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have a MySQL database I use for a software I have made where teachers can upload assignments, students can deliver their assignments and teachers can evaluate these deliveries. Now I want to list a overview over which assignment has the most comments on the deliveries in descending order.

All assignments are stored in a table called module where module_id is PK. All deliveries are stored in a table called delivery where delivery_id is PK and both user_id and module_id is FK. Last but not least we have the student_comment table where all comments are stored. In that table Student_comment_id is PK and delivery_id is FK. If my explanation was horrible, I`ve listed under how I made the tables. There are obviously more tables but I think they are irrelevant to this question.

```
create table module(
module_id int not null auto_increment,
module_name varchar(50) not null,
description varchar(1000),
rights int,
primary key(module_id)
);

create table delivery(
delivery_id int not null auto_increment,
module_id int,
users_id int,
delivery_status int,
date_delivered date,
date_approved date,
primary key(delivery_id),
foreign key(module_id) references module(module_id),
foreign key(users_id) references users(users_id)
);

create table student_comment(
student_comment_id int not null auto_increment primary key,
s_content varchar(100),
delivery_id int,
foreign key(delivery_id) references delivery(delivery_id));
```

So again, I want to list a overview over which module have the most comments on the deliveries and I want to sort it in a descending order. I have tried this for a while now but cant really figure out how to do this. Any help is really appreciated!

Also, I have just started with SQL so if there is something you think is wrong or you have a great source of information which can help me, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An aggregate query should produce what you're asking for.  When you say "which module have the most comments on the deliveries," I interpret that to mean that you want to know the number of comments on all of the deliveries.  The following SQL should produce that for you.

```
select
    m.module_id,
    count(c.student_comment_id) as comment_count
from
    module as m
    inner join delivery as d on d.module_id=m.module_id
    inner join student_comment as c on c.delivery_id=d.delivery_id
group by
    m.module_id
order by
    count(c.student_comment_id) desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer NIelsen. I am probably just a noob at this but I could not seem to get your code to work.. I get this: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'm.module' in 'field list'. What am I missing here? Just for reference, I use MySQL workbench.

Comment: Also, just to be specific: Each module(assignment) has x numbers of deliveries. I want to count how many comments there is in totalt for each of these modules(assignments).

Comment: Now I get this error: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'c.comment' in 'field list'. I dont really understand how to fix this..

Comment: Just my sloppy typing.  I have corrected it to "comment_id".  Any column from the "student_comment" table (aliased as "c") could be used instead.  This is a straightforward set of joins with an aggregate (indicated by the 'count()' function and the GROUP BY clause).  This kind of thing is common, so is probably worth studying a bit.

Comment: Yeah I really need to read up on more SQL. I have to bother you again because i still get the same error only now it is on the c.comment_id in field list.

Comment: The query is simple, but this typing thing seems to be hard (for me).  I ran your CREATE TABLE statements myself--thanks for including those--and then the (further edited) aggregate query. It should work for you now.

Comment: Haha now it works! Thank you a lot Nielsen, I was just about to go crazy over this. Your help is really appreciated!